# Python string format calling a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

Is there a way to format with the new format syntax a string from a function call?

For example:

```python
"my request url was {0.get_full_path()}".format(request)
```

So it calls the function `get_full_path()` function **inside** the string and not as a parameter in the format function.

---

#### EDIT

Here is another example that will probably show my frustration better, this is what I would like:

```python
"{0.full_name()} {0.full_last_name()} and my nick name is {0.full_nick_name()}".format(user)
```

This is what I want to avoid:

```python
"{0} and {1} and my nick name is {2}".format(user.full_name(), user.full_last_name(), user.full_nick_name())
```

Comment: No, you can't.  What difference will it make though doing `"my request url was {0}".format(request.get_full_path())`?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you need something like that?

Comment: what I want to avoid is something like this: `"my request url was {0} and my post was {1}".format(request.get_full_path(), request.POST)`. I want to use the same object only once

Comment: What's bad about using the same object twice?

Comment: In fact, by doing it like you want, you're still using the same object twice.

Comment: @SimeonVisser I just like more a syntax where I don't have to add the same object more than once in the format args

Comment: @Hassek: It is just a *reference*. You can assign the same value to another, short name: `r = request`, and use `'...'.format(`r.get_full_path(), r.POST)`. It doesn't matter that much does it? String formatting gives you some handy shortcuts, including indexing and attribute access, but function calling is *not* part of the format. These are not full-blown Python expressions, nor should they be.

Comment: @MartijnPieters any reason why they shouldn't be? my wild guess is that the format syntax takes the values from the object `__dict__` and that's why they can't call a function. but that doesn't makes it less of a pain to have to add the same object in the args (at least for me).

Comment: @Hassek: The string formatting is parsing a dedicated format. It is not the regular python parser parsing the references, so these are *not* Python expressions. There is no namespace, you could not pass in arguments if you *could* call functions, for example. The attribute and item access is a convenience to simplify many common formatting requirements, but this is *not* meant (nor will it ever be) a full Python expression parser.

Comment: @Hassek: Not being able to call anything has nothing to do with accessing the `__dict__` or anything else. It uses the standard methods to access attributes and items.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I see, very interesting. Thanks for those comments :)

Comment: Note that there are two answers that now give good approaches to do what you wanted, and which have more votes that the accepted answer.  You might want to give them some official recognition.

Comment: @nealmcb thanks for commenting, what I was looking got implemented in python 3.6 which is very exciting.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Python 3.6 adds literal string interpolation, which is written with an `f` prefix. See [PEP 0498 -- Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

This allows one to write

```
>>> x = 'hello'
>>> s = f'{x}'
>>> print(s)
hello
```

It should be noted that these are not actual strings, but represent code that evaluates to a string each time. In the above example, `s` will be of type `str`, with value `'hello'`. You can't pass an `f`-string around, since it will be evaluated to the result `str` before being used (unlike `str.format`, but like every other string literal modifier, such as `r'hello'`, `b'hello'`, `'''hello'''`). ([PEP 501 -- General purpose string interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0501/) (currently deferred) suggests a string literal that will evaluate to an object which can take substitutions later.)

Answer (score 20):

Not sure if you can modify the object, but you could modify or wrap the object to make the functions properties. Then they would look like attributes, and you could do it as

```
class WrapperClass(originalRequest):
    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return super(WrapperClass, self).full_name()

"{0.full_name} {0.full_last_name} and my nick name is {0.full_nick_name}".format(user)
```

which IS legal.

Comment: It also works with dicts. `'{0[hello]}'.format({'hello':'world'})` results in `'world'`.

Comment: Yes, this dict retrieval works out-of-the-box without having this WrapperClass, FYI

Comment: good to know (i thought that was added later), but the question was about calling functions, not really looking up dictionary items. literal string interpolation can do it though..

Answer (score 8):

Python does not directly support variable interpolation.  This means that it lacks certain functionality (namely, function calling in strings) which other languages support.

So, there isn't really anything to say here other than no, you can't do that.  That's just not how Python's [formatting syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) works.

The best you have is this:

```
"my request url was {0}".format(request.get_full_path())
```

Comment: Just made an edit, is not about the request object really. I am almost certain you are right about this, I just would like another syntax option that I guess doesn't exists :(

Answer (score 1):

What about this very weird thing?

```
"my request url was %s and my post was %s"\
    % (lambda r: (r.get_full_path(), r.POST))(request)
```

Explanation:

1. Classic way of formatting
2. Lambda function which takes a request and returns a tuple with what you want
3. Call the lambda inline as arguments for your string.

I still prefer the way you're doing it.

If you want readability you can do this:

```
path, post = request.get_full_path(), request.POST
"my request url was {} and my post was {}".format(path, post)
```

Comment: Yea I think that's just not worth it heh. I am looking more for a syntax that is permited there, for example, to format a datetime you can do `{:%Y}` and it works.

Comment: I'm sorry that's all I got :) I don't think Python goes so far. Especially, it's not famous for its string interpolation/formatting anyways :/

Comment: I'll just leave the question open for a while, but my hopes are low on this one :(

Answer (score 1):

So summary of methods would be

```py
(base) [1]~ $ cat r.py
# user is dict:
user = {'full_name': 'dict joe'}
print('{0[full_name]}'.format(user))

# user is obj:
class user:
    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return 'attr joe'


print('{0.full_name}'.format(user()))


# Wrapper for arbitray values - as dict or by attr
class Getter:
    def __init__(self, src):
        self.src = src

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return getattr(self.src, k, 'not found: %s' % k)

    __getattr__ = __getitem__


print('{0[foo]} - {0.full_name}'.format(Getter(user())))
(base) [1]~ $ python r.py
dict joe
attr joe
not found: foo - attr joe
```