# Formatting dict keys: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'keys()'

Tags: python, dictionary, methods, string-formatting, attributeerror

What is the proper way to format dict keys in string?

When I do this:

```
>>> foo = {'one key': 'one value', 'second key': 'second value'}
>>> "In the middle of a string: {foo.keys()}".format(**locals())
```

What I expect:

```
"In the middle of a string: ['one key', 'second key']"
```

What I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    "In the middle of a string: {foo.keys()}".format(**locals())
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'keys()'
```

But as you can see, my dict has keys:

```
>>> foo.keys()
['second key', 'one key']
```

Comment: which version on python?  2 or 3?

Comment: [Related, possibly dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19796123/python-string-format-calling-a-function)

Comment: @Kosh Python 2.7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't call methods in the placeholders. You can access properties and attributes and even index the value - but you can't call methods:

```
class Fun(object):
    def __init__(self, vals):
        self.vals = vals

    @property
    def keys_prop(self):
        return list(self.vals.keys())

    def keys_meth(self):
        return list(self.vals.keys())
```

Example with method (failing):

```
>>> foo = Fun({'one key': 'one value', 'second key': 'second value'})
>>> "In the middle of a string: {foo.keys_meth()}".format(foo=foo)
AttributeError: 'Fun' object has no attribute 'keys_meth()'
```

Example with property (working):

```
>>> foo = Fun({'one key': 'one value', 'second key': 'second value'})
>>> "In the middle of a string: {foo.keys_prop}".format(foo=foo)
"In the middle of a string: ['one key', 'second key']"
```

The formatting syntax makes it clear that you can only access attributes (a la `getattr`) or index (a la `__getitem__`) the placeholders (taken from ["Format String Syntax"](https://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)):

> The arg_name can be followed by any number of index or attribute expressions. An expression of the form `'.name'` selects the named attribute using `getattr()`, while an expression of the form `'[index]'` does an index lookup using `__getitem__()`.

---

With Python 3.6 you can easily do this with f-strings, you don't even have to pass in `locals`:

```
>>> foo = {'one key': 'one value', 'second key': 'second value'}
>>> f"In the middle of a string: {foo.keys()}"
"In the middle of a string: dict_keys(['one key', 'second key'])"

>>> foo = {'one key': 'one value', 'second key': 'second value'}
>>> f"In the middle of a string: {list(foo.keys())}"
"In the middle of a string: ['one key', 'second key']"
```

Comment: Yeah, I see. I'll remove my earlier comment. And this one in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

```
"In the middle of a string: {}".format(list(foo.keys()))
```

Comment: Please add a description of what?, why? and how? your code does. Someone who can understand it without an explanation doesn't need the code, either.

Answer (score 0):

```
"In the middle of a string: {}".format([k for k in foo])
```

Comment: You should try and explain your answers rather than just leaving a one liner of code with no context, it will help this asker and future visitors to the page

Answer (score 0):

As it was said by others above you cannot do it in the way you would prefer, here are additional information to follow [python string format calling a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19796123/6783277)