# How can i call this function definiton inside a print function?

Tags: python, function, printing

I created this function definition in python:

```py
def random_person():
    mylist = ["wounded priestress", "crying girl"]
    return random.choice(mylist)
```

Now I want to call that function in a print function in my code:

```py
print("In the temple, you find a random_person().")
```

Unfortunately, it does not result in the strings I have chosen for my random function.
This is what I get:

```
In the temple, you find a random_person().
```

Comment: Try `print(f"In the temple, you find a {random_person()}.")`

Comment: `print("In the temple, you find a "+random_person()+".")` is one way

Comment: Or `print("In the temple, you find a", random_person(), ".")`

Comment: if each word of a string was interpreted by python it would be very unconvenient right?

Comment: Or even `print("In the temple, you find a {}.".format(random_person()))`

Comment: *Or* `print("In the temple, you find a %s." % random_person())`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python string format calling a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19796123/python-string-format-calling-a-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just thought I'd compile all the options I listed in the comments :)

```
print(f"In the temple, you find a {random_person()}.") # my personal favorite
print("In the temple, you find a", random_person(), ".")
print("In the temple, you find a {}.".format(random_person()))
print("In the temple, you find a %s." % random_person())
```

And @Jean-Francois' too:

```
print("In the temple, you find a "+random_person()+".")
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
import random
def random_person():
   mylist = ["wounded priestress", "crying girl"]
   return random.choice(mylist)
print(f"In the temple, you find a {random_person()}.")
```

It uses f-strings a way better way than `+str()+`